# Remove the same character from strings in column

Tags: python, pandas, string, substring

I'm trying to remove a specific character in a specific position in a column. Is there any way that I can do it with the strip position type function? Any support is appreciated!! Thanks in advance!!

Sample df

```
Report
RPi-1
RPi-2
RPi-3
RPi-4
```

I would like to remove the 'i' at position 3 of the string on every row within Report column.

Desired df

```
Report
RP-1
RP-2
RP-3
RP-4
```

Comment: Use `df["Report"].str[:2].add(df["Report"].str[3:])` if you want to work on positions instead of replacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Report'] = df['Report'].str.replace('RPi', 'RP')
```

or

```
df["Report"]=df["Report"].str.replace("i","")
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I find the first option fits my situation the best. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

This works. You can replace "i" with any arbitrary charactr that you want to replace

`df[col]=df[col].apply(lambda x: x.replace("i", ""))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a character at a particular position, you can do it using [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html):

```
df.Report = df.Report.replace(df.Report.str[2], '') ## str[2] gives 3rd character
```

Output:

```
  Report
0   RP-1
1   RP-2
2   RP-3
3   RP-4
```